# What does + preceding command do in vim

Tags: command

What does + preceding command do in vim, for example from this command from [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Implement_your_own_interactive_finder_without_plugins) website:

```
     botright 10new +setlocal\ buftype=nofile\ bufhidden=wipe\
       \ nobuflisted\ nonumber\ norelativenumber\ noswapfile\ nowrap\
       \ foldmethod=manual\ nofoldenable\ modifiable\ noreadonly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` isn't *preceding* the `setlocal` command, so much as *following* the `:new` command: it's running the `setlocal` command in the newly created window.

See [`:help :new`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#%3Anew) and [`:help +cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%2Bcmd) for more details.